# AWK: how to read columnwise file to AWK-script in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
$ cat read.sh 
#!bin/bash

// how can I read the columnwise data to awk-script?
awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' read
$ cat data 
1
2
3
4
5
$ . ./read.sh <data
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `read' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: any reasons why you are doing this instead of passing a file name , since you already have the file.

Comment: @ghostdog74: none at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `filename` from the end of the `awk` command:

Change

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' read
```

to

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

The 1st one tell `awk` to get the input from a file named `read` where as the 2nd one tells `awk` to get the input from `standard input`.

The way you are running the script: `./read.sh <data`
You are supplying the input through standard input.

Alternatively if you always want the script to read input from the file named `data`, you can do:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' data
```

and run the script as: `./read.sh`

Comment: You can also use - as the filename for stdin instead of leaving it blank.  I find that easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Also, your she-bang line is garbled; it should be `#!/bin/bash`.  But this should work instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ sum += $1 }
END { print sum }
```